# how to run spark job in aws lambda with out spinning up the cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-lambda

Trying to use AWS lambda spark event based trigger once the file.csv  is uploaded to s3 ,execute the backend code and put the results in other(output) bucket, help appreciated.

Comment: I assume you are trying to avoid a cluster setup overhead for a small task. Have you considered AWS Elastic Container Service instead? Many companies widely use it for this use case.

Comment: yes is there any approach in aws lambda to run a simple spark job ? thanks in advance

Comment: You can set a bucket notification event to trigger a lambda function everytime a csv is uploaded and use that lambda function to invoke a Glue Job with spark code.
But, if you will not make any transformation in the file you can simply use boto3 code in lambda to move from one bucket to another one, or use pandas instead of spark on lambda.